# Consuming web service using wsdl in Domino

Tags: lotus-domino

We use web service Consumers\ Providors quite a bit in our application, both LS and java design elements.

I have a web service (wcf) wsdl that I am trying to import into a LotusScript Web Consumer design element and when saving I am getting the following error:

Not a member: INVOKE

...on line indicated below.

Function GetCopyDestinations(service As XSD_STRING, ocsCode As XSD_STRING, Fault1 As InteropErrorInfoStruct_n1) As ArrayOfInteropMessageDestination_n1
    Set GetCopyDestinations = Service.Invoke("GetCopyDestinations", service, ocsCode, Fault1)   <<<<=====ERROR ON THIS LINE
End Function

I take this to be that the wsdl --> Web service classes transformer does not like the structure of the wsdl...?  I work with the developer who is creating the service we are consuming, so I can get the structure changed, but, from error above, I am not really sure where to start.  I assume this means it does not think the Object Service has the method .Invoke().

I've had a look in the file: lsxsd.lss, which LS web service elements include.  The "stub" class in the LS web service inherits from PortTypeBase which is in the lsxsd.lss file, PortTypeBase does not have an invoke() method, so I am not quite sure how\ where this method is inherited from.   Other LS web services we use successfully, have exactly the same structure, so it would appear this is correct.

The only thing I can think of is to get my colleague to strip the wsdl back to bare bones, then add 1 method, see if it imports, add another, see if it imports, etc.

As a side note, I tried to import the ws into a java consumer, it imports fine.  I then construct the stub in exactly the same way I do for all our other java consumer services, which it appears to do successfully. When I run my test harness agent, the stub is created, but it errors when trying to run any of the actions:

java.rmi.RemoteException: No operation description was found for the service

I take this to mean, it can't find the action in the wsdl file, or something similar...?  The end point url and PortName appear correct if I output as it is running.

As a side note to this...the service I am attempting to consume above, we have a version working in production now, it is in a LS web consumer, but new one has had new actions added.  For a sanity check, I then imported the "live" wsdl...which we know works...into a LS web consumer design element and run a test harness agent, works as expected...good.  Then I imported "live" wsdl into a java consumer design element.  When running the service, we get the same error...!?

java.rmi.RemoteException: No operation description was found for the service

So now I'm really, really confused.  I would like to post the wsdl here, but I think NDA etc., will not allow me, but if it's any help, I am constructing the stub as follows:

ITKInteropV10Stub stub = (ITKInteropV10Stub) new ITKInteropServiceV10_ServiceLocator().getITKInteropV10();

This is a similar stub constructor pattern to all other java web services I consume.

I have been googling\ searching for a couple of days now, searching for errors listed above, I'm really struggling to find a way forward.

Ideally, solving the import in the LS web consumer would work best, since back end logic is currently in LS Script libs which will access this service. If I get it working in java, that's fine as well, it just makes the retrieval of data from the Web Service into the LS libs a bit more complex.

Any comments\ suggestion would be welcomed with open arms!

Regards

Nick

Comment: I answered this on LDD for you, but might as well try and get some points here. :) Let me know if it resolves the issue.

Comment: Great you are sorted, with regards to the other issue I'd recommend testing with SOAPUI or similar app. In case you haven't used it before here is a tutorial. http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/Testing_your_Domino_web_service_provider_and_consumer_using_SoapUI._ .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LotusScript is not case sensitive. You have a variable called "service" of XSD_STRING and another object called "Service" which looks like it might be a NotesWebServiceEngine object? (internal LS object).

Comment: Thanks Simon, you are indeed correct.  Get that man a beer!  They changed variable name their end, all sorted in LotusScript Web service design element.  I still can't get it to work in java, same error, whilst I don't need to use the java version, it's really bugging me why I can't get it to work: java.rmi.RemoteException: No operation description was found for the service