# call a service web in an agent JAVA, error : RemoteException: No operation description was found for the service

Tags: java, web-services, lotus-domino

I try to call a web service java in a agent java.
I have this error :

```
error message: java.rmi.RemoteException: No operation description was found for the service {http://tempuri.org/}ServiceFichier
 error message:  at org.tempuri.BasicHttpBinding_IServiceAccesFichierStub.getHelloWord(Unknown Source)
 error message:  at JavaAgent.NotesMain(Unknown Source)
 error message:  at lotus.domino.AgentBase.runNotes(Unknown Source)
 error message:  at lotus.domino.NotesThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I call a web service with this code :

```
public class JavaAgent extends AgentBase {

    public void NotesMain() {

      try {
          Session session = getSession();
          AgentContext agentContext = session.getAgentContext();

          String test;

        URL endpoint;
        try 
        {
            endpoint = new URL("http://nomserveur:numeroport/AccesFichier/ServiceAccesFichier.svc?wsdl");       

            ServiceFichierLocator service1 = new ServiceFichierLocator();
            
            BasicHttpBinding_IServiceAccesFichierStub service = new BasicHttpBinding_IServiceAccesFichierStub(endpoint,service1);         
            
            test = service.getHelloWord();
        
            
            
            System.out.println(test + " ********************************************");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Bloc catch auto-généré
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Fault e) {
            // TODO Bloc catch auto-généré
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            // TODO Bloc catch auto-généré
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

      } catch(Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
```

I import the web service in an web consumer in notes domino designer 9.0.1.
The web service works and it built in dotnet.

Answer (score 0):

I did a Google search for the error "No operation description was found for the service" and found this other SO posting.

(link corrected)
[Consuming web service using wsdl in Domino](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13065359/consuming-web-service-using-wsdl-in-domino)

The posting relates to a LotusScript Web Service, but the issue I believe is the same. Both LotusScript and .Net are case insensitive regarding their method/function declarations.

Reading the stack trace you're calling .helloWord(), could that you have a name mismatch between your service and consumer ?

Comment: sorry but the link is bad, it called the same question...^^

Comment: @sissi49 It's a long time though but do you remember what you did to make it work? I am facing the exact same error and don't know how to solve this.